# Set image as background of options menu

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I was wondering is it possible to set a repeating picture as background of options menu instead of classical black color?

I would like to set something like this as my background:

[image]

Comment: I have possible one solution, but I don't think it will look good across all devices (this method "stretches" the picture so that it'll fit into the action bar)
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)
Go to this link on the left and use the first answer, but instead of inserting a random hex color code, you would instead use:
@drawable/checkerboard_picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a drawable bitmap named **menu_background.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:src="@drawable/my_background_image" />
```

Then, custom your **styles.xml** as follows:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/mListDropDown</item>
</style>  

<style name="mListDropDown" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/menu_background"</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">...</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">...</item>
</style>
```

However, you will have many troubles to do the same for all devices - mainly the repeat mode: [XML drawable Bitmap tileMode bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586209/xml-drawable-bitmap-tilemode-bug). This bug is known and ***"partially fixed in Android 3.0 and completely fixed in ICS"***, see the comments on the accepted answer: *"An easy workaround is to change the tiling mode from code"*. Also, you will able to achieve this on lower version with the `panelFullBackground` attribute, see this example: [How can I change the Options menu background for Android 2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552776/2668136).

I think that it's as heavy as useless. You will waste a lot of time to do it. Maybe you should reconsider your design by using a **9-patch drawable** or the default android design. I hope this will be helpful.